# infinite loop malloc in a 32 bit kernel with 4 Gb RAM and 10 Gb Swap Partition

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system

Let's say I have a 32-bit kernel. 4 Gb RAM, 10 Gb Swap Partition.

I have a process which has malloc in an infinite loop. So, eventually system's OOM would kill the process. Here are two arguments.

Argument 1: Since, it's 32 bit Kernel with a  Virtual address split of 3:1 i.e. 3Gb for user space and 1 Gb for Kernel space. The process would be allocated 3 Gb of memory and then there is no more memory to give. So, OOM would kill the process.

Argument 2: Since, it's 32 bit Kernel with a  Virtual address split of 3:1 i.e. 3Gb for user space and 1 Gb for Kernel space. The process would be allocated 4 Gb of memory and then there is no more memory to give. So, OOM would kill the process.

Argument 3: Malloc would first take 4 Gb memory of Ram, Then it would take 10 Gb of Swap partition and Then OOM would kill the process.

Which of these arguments (if any) is true ?

There are other answer's on forum but I am not sure whether the answer to this question depends on whether its 32 bit kernel or 64 bit kernel ?

Comment: no. your system effectively has 14gig of memory. but no single process on a 32bit system can have more than 4gig allocated to it, regardless of the actual 1:3-split stuff occuring. technically the swap file wouldn't get touched at all, assuming that 4gig ram was completely empty.

Comment: Let's say, 1 gig of a processes' virtual memory (high memory region) is reserved for kernel operations. The user space can use the remaining 3 gig. This is a 3/1 split. Shouldn't malloc only take 3 Gb of user space ? Since it's user level process.

Comment: @saurabhagarwal, *no* virtual memory is reserved for kernel operations.  The kernel operates in real mode.  Or to put it another way, the kernel's memory does not occupy any part of the virtual memory assigned to any process.  Each process's virtual memory space belongs to it, and it alone.

Comment: Well, now it makes sense. Thanks for pointing it out.but then what is the meaning of kernel user split of virtual address space ? What is the significance of this split ?

Comment: malloc can fail, or can over-commit, or both. there's no universal and reliable way to use malloc to trigger OOM handler.

Comment: I think to see the OOM killer kick in, you need to do a mlockall() and then malloc else a lot of the ANON pages you are not touching would be swapped out and you would not be using that memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do think OOM will kill the process? In your example you will exhaust your address space earlier than you will use up all of your real memory. So in your example (32-bit) you will be able to allocate around 3 GB of address space (minus text/data/stack and other segments and also possible memory fragmentation) and then the system will just return ENOMEM.

If you're on 64-bit system, things get more interesting. Now the result will heavily depend on whether you really are using this memory or not. If you're not using it (just allocating), then due to overcommit (if, of course, you don't have it disabled) you will be able to allocate some huge amounts of address space, but if you try to use it, that's where (around 10+4 GB boundary) you will trigger OOM and that will kill the program.

#### update

It's actually quite easy to check with a program like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    static char *allocs[10 * 1024 * 1024];
    static unsigned int size;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int const chunk = 1024 * 1024;

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(allocs)/sizeof(allocs[0])); i++)
        if ((allocs[i] = malloc(chunk)) == NULL) {
            printf("failed to allocate after %u MB: %s\n", i, strerror(errno));
            break;
        }

    size = i;
    if (size == (sizeof(allocs)/sizeof(allocs[0])))
         printf("allocated %u MB successfully!\n", size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        memset(allocs[i], 1, chunk);
        if (i % 100 == 0)
            printf("memset %u MB\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It tries to allocate 10M of memory chunks, each 1M in size, so effectively that's 10 TB. On 32-bit system with 4 GB of RAM it gives this result (shortened a bit):

```
failed to allocate after 3016 MB: Cannot allocate memory
memset 0 MB
memset 100 MB
...
memset 2900 MB
memset 3000 MB
```

As expected, there is just not enough address space and adding swap (I've done my tests with 5GB instead of 10) doesn't help in any way.

With 64 bit it behaves a bit unexpectedly (this is without swap, just 4 GB of RAM) in that it doesn't output anything and just gets killed by OOM killer while still doing allocations. But that's explainable looking at OOM killer log:

```
[  242.827042] [ 5171]  1000  5171 156707933   612960  306023        0             0 a.out
[  242.827044] Out of memory: Kill process 5171 (a.out) score 905 or sacrifice child
[  242.827046] Killed process 5171 (a.out) total-vm:626831732kB, anon-rss:2451812kB, file-rss:28kB
```

So it was able to allocate around 620 GB (!) of virtual memory with 2.4 really mapped. Remember also, that we're allocating with `malloc()`, so the C library has to do its own housekeeping and even if you estimate it to be around 0.5% overhead with such big allocations you get substantial numbers just for that (to be free of that overhead you can try using `mmap()`). At this stage we have enough memory used to be short of it, so the process gets killed while still doing allocations. If you're to make it less greedy and change allocs to `[100 * 1024]` (which is just 100 GB effectively), you can easily see the effect of swap, because without it on 4 GB system you have:

```
allocated 102400 MB successfully!
memset 0 MB
memset 100 MB
...
memset 2800 MB
memset 2900 MB
Killed
```

And with 5 GB of swap added:

```
allocated 102400 MB successfully!
memset 0 MB
memset 100 MB
...
memset 7900 MB
memset 8000 MB
Killed
```

All as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first clarify your requirements slightly. You want to run a 32-bit process. It is allocating memory in a tight loop and changing it. The last part is necessary as otherwise only address space is reserved, but no memory is committed to it.

Your program will consume resources up to the usable part of the 32-bit virtual address space. For most 32-bit UNIX-like kernels on x86, this will be 3GB as the top 1GB is reserved for the kernel itself. Linux has a build time option to change this to a 2GB:2GB split. If you run under Xen, the kernel uses a separate address space, so your program can actually consume the full 4GB. Other CPU architectures generally fall somewhere between those two cases.

Now that we have established that the program will use between 3GB and 4GB memory top, let's look at the resources the kernel has available. If you have 10GB swap, it can always push enough pages into swap to keep the program running. Assuming there are no other programs running with large allocations, you will never hit the OOM killer as you haven't run out of memory in first place.

One last word about the OOM killer. If you don't change the memory allocated and you run multiple instances of your program (e.g. > 5), they still won't consume more than a couple of MB of actual memory (RAM+swap). This is the so-called memory overcommit. Now, if the programs start to change the allocations, they will slowly reduce the available RAM+swap and run out at some point. This is the situation when the OOM killer triggers. Without memory overcommit, malloc would be returning an error as soon as the sum of the sizes of all running processes is larger than RAM+swap. This is slightly simplified as certain kinds of memory mappings don't count.